# Stack array losing previous values for single page submission

Tags: php, arrays, stack

I'm trying to do the push-and-pop stack array in PHP but only the last value is stored. How can I store the other values as well even if I click on the button again & load the same page?
This is what I've done:

```
<?php
    if(!$_GET)
        $myStack = array();
    else
        $myStack[] = "";
?>

<html>
<head> <title>Exercise</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="get">
        Element: <input type="text" name="num"  value="0"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="push" value="push" />
        <input type="submit" name="pop" value="pop" />
    </form>

<?php

    if(isset($_GET["push"])){
        array_push($myStack, $_GET["num"]);
        foreach($myStack as $val)
            echo $val . " ";
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET["pop"])){
        array_pop($myStack);
        foreach($myStack as $val)
            echo $val . " ";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your values are not stored in between HTTP requests, you must use Session variables for storing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every http request php will execute script with all variables from scratch. You have to use [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) or `static` variables to save values between requests. 
 To store array in `$_SESSION` just assign it to key:

```
$_SESSION["myStack"] = array();
$_SESSION["myStack"][] = 1;
$_SESSION["myStack"][] = 2;
```

Comment: I've tried using SESSION earlier but I don't know how to store more than one value on it.. I'm only able to store 1, not an array.. Please demonstrate..

Comment: wow.. push worked.. i did: <?php session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['myStack'])){
        $_SESSION["myStack"] = array();
    }
    else{
        if(isset($_GET["push"])){
            $_SESSION["myStack"][] = $_GET["num"];
            foreach($_SESSION["myStack"] as $val)
                echo $val . " ";
            }

    }
?>

Comment: THANKS! JUST 1 MORE: HOW TO DO THE POP? OR HOW CAN I DELETE THE LAST VALUE FROM THE SESSION?

Comment: array_pop($_SESSION['myStack'])

Answer (score 0):

You have a reset at the top off your script. After reload your stack will be empty. Also you have to save your stack into a session var.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code with using a session to store the array:

```
<?php
//starts the session
session_start();
$myStack = array();

//gets the array from the session if it exists
if (isset($_SESSION['stack']))
    $myStack = $_SESSION['stack'];

?>
<html>
    <head> <title>Exercise</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="get">
    Element: <input type="text" name="num"  value="0"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="push" value="push" />
    <input type="submit" name="pop" value="pop" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_GET["push"])){
    array_push($myStack, $_GET["num"]);
    foreach($myStack as $val)
        echo $val . " ";
}
elseif(isset($_GET["pop"])){
    array_pop($myStack);
    foreach($myStack as $val)
        echo $val . " ";
}

//stores the array in the opened session
$_SESSION['stack'] = $myStack;
?>
</body>
</html>
```